# mysql column alias not working, have to create an empty concatenation to make it work

Tags: mysql, jdbc

if i do:

```
SELECT PEvent.publicID AS 'ID'...
```

Results come  as "publicID" not as "ID"

to make it work i have to do:

```
SELECT concat(PEvent.publicID, '') AS 'ID'
```

why?

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
maxActive="10" maxIdle="3" maxWait="1000" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
maxActive="10" maxIdle="3" maxWait="1000" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
maxActive="10" maxIdle="3" maxWait="1000" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
maxActive="10" maxIdle="3" maxWait="1000" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
```

a very bad thing that something as simple as a column alias does not work...

Comment: It works for me. How are you testing it?

Comment: I've noticed this problem with sqlfiddle.com, but not when I use MySQL monitor or use it from a programming language like PHP.

Comment: @Barmar with a jdbc query.

Comment: Upvote because I had the exact same problem in sqldeveloper (I'll be happy with the concat solution for now)

Comment: I had the same problem. On a side note you don't need the 2nd argument in concat() to get the alias to work: SELECT CONCAT(PEvent.publicID) ID

Comment: just an FYI CONCAT with no second argument doesn't work on H2 but with the 2nd argumetn does work on most dbs

Also thank you for this question. The Concat was a good solution for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine for me when I tested this from my ubuntu mysql command line, and MySQL Workbench for Windows. I figured it might be a jdbc thing, and searched around. MySQL doesn't consider this as a bug.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21596

From the comment on the BZ,

> This is a change required for JDBC-compliance. RSMD.getColumnName() is required to return the actual column name. Aliases are returned via RSMD.getColumnLabel().
>
> If you want the older non-compliant behavior from Connector/J 3.1, use the "useOldAliasMetadataBehavior" configuration parameter present in the 5.0 nightly builds, and set it to "true".

Comment: so, if aliases aren't fully equivalent to column names what is the purpose of them ? the whole thing is absurd. Thanks for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Also an option to use

```
ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel()
```

as mentioned here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing-upgrading-5-1.html