# ResultSet Value of Aliased Column without Column Index

Tags: java, spring-boot, resultset, jdbctemplate

I'm running the following query using a jdbc template against a MySQL db:

```
SELECT d.*, a.mongo_id as yyyyy_profile_mongo_id,t.mongo_id as targeting_profile_mongo_id, CAST(xxxxx_type AS SIGNED) AS xxxxx_type_int
LEFT JOIN zzzzz t on t.id = d.targeting_profile_id
LEFT JOIN yyyyy a on a.id = d.yyyyy_profile_id
FROM xxxxx d
```

When attempting to get a string from a ResultSet using the aliased name "**targeting_profile_mongo_id**" I get a "**Invalid Column Name**" error

[image]

I can see in the debugger that even though I did "**as targeting_profile_mongo_id**" the columnName still shows as the original value of "mongo_id" and only the column label is changed.

[image]

**Are there any work arounds here without having to loop through the metadata to find the column index?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after some more digging! Looks like you can somehow get around this by putting a concat around the columns causing the issue.

like this

```
SELECT d.*, CONCAT(a.mongo_id,'') as yyyyy_profile_mongo_id,CONCAT(t.mongo_id,'') as targeting_profile_mongo_id, CAST(xxxxx_type AS SIGNED) AS xxxxx_type_int
LEFT JOIN zzzzz t on t.id = d.targeting_profile_id
LEFT JOIN yyyyy a on a.id = d.yyyyy_profile_id
FROM xxxxx d
```

[mysql column alias not working, have to create an empty concatenation to make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775548/mysql-column-alias-not-working-have-to-create-an-empty-concatenation-to-make-it)